# Magento 2: Frontend and Backend not show properly?

Tags: magento2

[image]
[image]

I have reloaded it many times, I was able to reproduce it.

Any idea about that?

Comment: Did you run static content deploy content? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: Nope I didn't,can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Should follow the guide above.

Comment: is this thing  can be done during installation procedures so that I will re-install again to load css.

Comment: run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: it worked when i included  $php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  -f

Answer (score 0):

we can run ,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```